# A webserver which runs user java code and then returns results to webbrowser

Tags: java, webserver

I am new to java programming and Let me explain what i intend to achieve.

1. I have java class files present on a Linux machine.
2. I want to run these remotely from other machines and obtain the results (testng results or junit) back into the windows machine.

My approach

1. create a webserver which has my scripts (on the Linux machine).
2. Use webbrowser to connect to it and execute the java classes and then push the results from server to the webbrowser.

could you please provide me the links where i can learn to accomplish this task or if you have much better approach , guide me.

Comment: What is a "java script" as per your definition? Java source files? JavaScript code? This is not clear!

Comment: java class files which i want to execute.

Comment: So basically, to strip it down: you need to run specified shell commands on the Linux box (invoking `java MyClass.class` or similar), and serve the content of the resulting stdout back?

Comment: Are you running tests remotely? Maybe you should use some kind of CI server (e.g Continuum, Jenkins)

Comment: exactly ppeterka . if not stdout , push the  results html or xml file back to webbrowser to display.I mean Testng test results .

Comment: Hi Andras , yes i want to run the tests remotely.Yeah i shall learn about jenkins to check if it suits my requirement.Thanks

Comment: how about using tomcat webserver and then can we use the servlets to trigger the execution of the java class files and pump out the results back to browser.?